# Embedded .swf file in .pfd-Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: flash, pdf, adobe-reader, embedded-system, swf

I have just finished a presentation in LaTeX. In this very .pdf file I have included a .swf animation(done with adobe flash CS5 in windows) which starts when you click on it.

While I have already installed a relevant player(swfdec flash player) neither document viewer nor okular are able to reproduce it. I tried with my player to make sure that the file is not corrupted and the result was that it can be produced.

I tried the same .pdf file in windows using adobe reader and there is no problem there. The embedded file can be reproduced with no problem.

So I thought of installing adobe in ubuntu. I tried there to see if the problem was solved. Things got a bit better. Adobe could understand that there is something there, so when clicked I got a message that I had to get the proper player. When I clicked on a relevant button I expected to open my browser in a player's page. Instead nothing happened.

If I place my mouse's cursor next to the space that defines my animation the is a "message" stating "Media File(application/x-shockwave flash)". The next step was to install Adobe Flash player, but I couldn't find the standallone player;only the browser's plugs...

How can I get this .swf file play in pdf?

Answer (score 0):

First of all install [gnash](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnash) [image: Install gnash], which can be used as a standalone swf player. As you said, you were using LaTeX, you can write something like `\href{run:/tmp/test.swf}` in your file.

These steps are explained in more details on [tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48408).

Answer (score 0):

As alternative, you can embed a flash movie (SWF) into PDf file and play SWF file in Ubuntu using Adobe Reader version < 9.4-2 (version `9.4.1` is recommended as it is the last version for Linux with a built-in Flash player, you can find it [here](ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.4.1/enu/)). The embedding is possible using `flashmovie` LaTeX package, for example:

`\flashmovie[width=10cm,height=5cm,auto=1]{yournameforvideofile.swf}`

I have recently tested it again in current Ubuntu 16.04 and TeXlive 2015 LaTeX distribution and it works well.